# Declare global array variable in Yii

Tags: yii

```
$arr = array();

function test($status){
    global $arr;
    array_push($arr,$status);
}
```

How can I declare **$arr** as global array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set global variable in Yii use:

```
Yii::app()->params['arr'] = array();
```

to get variable:

```
echo Yii::app()->params['arr'];
```

Or you can place them in the `main.php` config file for each application.